# Angular same page with different routes and content

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

Imagine I have two type of routes in my angular application :

`/football` and `/basketball` and I have separate components for these routes.

Now I have details page. details page is quite complicated and both football and basketball have same layout for details page, so I have one component for it and route like that: `/details`, not `/football/details` or `/basketball/details`. these are mini games, and in details page I can open both football and basketball game at the same time, so I think `/football/details` or `/basketball/details` routes implementation is logically wrong.

Layout is same but I need several things to be done differently inside details page depending I open details page from football page or basketball page, so I should know I am on football details page or basketball details page. So what will be the best route architecture for this kind of problem? I mean should I use queryParams? or maybe I am doing something wrong? what will be the best practice?

Comment: Yes use `queryParams` and let your details component know route is coming from football or basketball.

Answer (score 2):

In the above scenario, to determine from which route you are landed on component page, you can either use queryparams or pass with data object in routing module.Below are the use cases of both.

```
1) this.router.navigate(['/path'], { queryParams: { type: 'football'} });
2) {
    path: '',
    component: detailsComponent,
    data: {
      type: 'football'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If it's the same page with different functionality, I would suggest using the `/details` route with `queryParams` - then create a service to handle the custom logic.